# Clang: error compiling c++ Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clang, llvm

I am trying to run SPEC2017 benchmarks using llvm testsuite according to LLVM's [Test Suite Guide](https://llvm.org/docs/TestSuiteGuide.html). My cmake command succeeds, but with make, I get errors in include files like numeric_traits.h. I get the error for every occurrence of `__is_signal` in `numeric_traits.h` and `stl_algobase.h`.

CMake command:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="/usr/bin/clang-7" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="/usr/bin/clang++-7" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" -C../test-suite/cmake/caches/O3.cmake -DTEST_SUITE_SPEC2017_ROOT:STRING="../speccpu2017" ../test-suite
...
$ make
...
In file included from /home/speccpu2017/benchspec/CPU/526.blender_r/src/blender/source/blender/render/intern/raytrace/rayobject_qbvh.cpp:37:
In file included from /home/speccpu2017/benchspec/CPU/526.blender_r/src/blender/source/blender/render/intern/raytrace/vbvh.h:34:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/algorithm:61:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:63:

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/ext/numeric_traits.h:63:25: error: expected member name or ';' after
      declaration specifiers
      static const bool __is_signed = __glibcxx_signed(_Value);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/ext/numeric_traits.h:74:50: error: expected unqualified-id
    const bool __numeric_traits_integer<_Value>::__is_signed;
                                                 ^    
[Long error. Truncated for clarity]
```

Setup:

- Clang version 7
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- linux: 4.18.0-25-generic
- Spec version: 2017

Comment: [Possible source of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/10957435). though without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Is your compiler able to properly compile at all? Have you tried compiling a simple file containing `#include<algorithm>` to make sure?

Comment: You should use `cmake ... V=1` for the verbose out, which should include compiler options. My guess is - and it is purely a guess - `is_signed<T>` is being called on a custom struct that lacks a numeric conversion. That's because `__glibcxx_signed` is `#define __glibcxx_signed(_Tp) ((_Tp)(-1) < 0)` in `numeric_traits.h`. You should probably switch to `numeric_limits::is_signed` instead of the lightweight helper in `numeric_traits.h`. (Read the headnotes in `/usr/include/c++/8/ext/numeric_traits.h`).

Answer (score 1):

Put this into portability flags for CXX https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/Docs/benchmarks/flags/526.blender_r.flags.html#b526.blender_r_D__BOOL_DEFINED

FYI, `<SPEC_SRC>/config/Example-clang-llvm-linux-x86.cfg` or `<SPEC_SRC>/config/Example-aocc-linux-x86.cfg` contains Clang-specific portability flags.